# k3s ctr images import to different dir

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, containerd, k3s

I am having tar of my service specific images. I am importing it in containerd so that it will be used by k3s to deploy PODs. command used to import image's tar is-
`k3s ctr images import XXX.tar`

By default it loads images in `/var/lib/rancher/data` dir. However, I would like to load images in different directory. Anyone know, how to specify custom directory while loading images?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find anything that may natively allow for changing this directory.
This doesn't mean nothing can be done. You can always create a symlink like this:

```
ln -s target_path /var/lib/rancher/data
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: thats right however I am mounting an external disk and would like to store all data there.

Comment: Have you thought about mounting this external disk in `/var/lib/rancher/data` dir? Could this possibly solve your problem??

Comment: I already thought of that..but somehow it doesn't feet for me due to some other dependency.